# Как выровнять текст по центру картинки? 5

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image]

Пытаюсь выровнять текст, но он съезжает.

[Ссылка на мой код](https://pastebin.com/q4nrSAvN)

```css
.half2 {
  background: green;
}

.contact {
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/000000);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

a {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="half2">
  <h2>Want To Hire Akona?</h2><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br> adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt<br> ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br><br><br>
  <a href="" class="contact">Contact Us »</a>
</div>
```

Comment: И что куда съезжает? И какой конечный результат хотелось бы получить?

Answer (score 1):

Так вроде бы

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.items {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
}

.item:nth-of-type(2) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x50/fc0" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>something text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для фона задай к примеру `height: 20px` и к тексту 
столько же `line-height: 20px`

Comment: + вертикальное выравнивание